# Highlighting rows in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I  am using bootstrap-table and that's my pen: [codepen](http://codepen.io/irainbow/pen/jydQKE)

I need to highlight rows (in 2nd and 3rd table) with the same ID I have selected in the 1st table.

How can I select/deselect them? I guess I have to add the `selected` class to the rows? I have tried to do that but it doesn't seems to work unfortunately.

Here is what I have tried:

```
if ($('tr[class="selected"]')) {
   var temp = $('tr[class="selected"]').attr("data-index");
   $('tr[data-index="' + temp + '"]').addClass('selected');
}
```

Furthermore, why is there ascending ordering in the tables? How can I keep the original sequence of json objects?

Comment: In codepen the original order seems to be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your listeners with the following scripts :

```
$('#eventsTable').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row, element) {

     var id = Number(element.attr('data-index')) + 1;
     $('#eventsTable2 tr:eq('+id+')').addClass('selected');
     $('#eventsTable3 tr:eq('+id+')').addClass('selected');
});

$('#eventsTable').on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row, element) {  

     var id = Number(element.attr('data-index')) + 1;     
     $('#eventsTable2 tr:eq('+id+')').removeClass('selected');
     $('#eventsTable3 tr:eq('+id+')').removeClass('selected');
});
```